# Update embedded JPG in SWF file without source FLA

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have an SWF file that I created long time ago with Action Script 2.0. There is an embedded JPG file in the SWF that I need to update for a client. Unfortunately, the original FLA file that I used to create it was lost when one of my backup drives crashed. I've played around with some 3rd party programs but none of them seem to be able to recompile the updated swf properly. I'd mention that I have Adobe Flash CC as an editor but just not the source file. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to best update the file. Thx in advance.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/ its the best one that I have used...

Comment: Sushi Hangover - your solution worked perfectly! Thanks a lot for your help